# Examples of non-compact connected spaces with the property...

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

I am looking for a non-compact connected space $X$ such that for any two disjoint closed $A,B\subseteq X$ there exists a proper closed connected $C\subseteq X$ such that $A\cup B\subseteq C$.

I would like the space to be normal if possible.

An example of a *compact* connected space with this property is the circle $S^1$: If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint closed sets in $S^1$ then $A\cup B\subsetneq S^1$ since $S^1$ is connected, so $S^1 \setminus (A\cup B)$ contains an open segment $(a,b)$. Then $S^1 \setminus (a,b)$ is as desired.

Note that the reals do not have this property.

Comment: All higher euclidean spaces should have this property. In essence, there are two unequal paths between a point on the boundary of $A$ and a point on the boundary of $B$ contained in the complement of their union. One dimensional fails because the complement can be a single path. I'm a little unsure right now how to make that rigorous, but it should be doable.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Ok, so like you think an open disc in the plane has this property?

Comment: That is my intuition, yes. The complement of the union is open so contains balls and therefore many potential paths. You just have to justify a path from one boundary to the other that stays in the complement (other than the endpoints).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an even easier way to show $\mathbb R^n$ has this for all $n\geq 2$, basically using your $S^1$ argument.

The complement of $A\cup B$ is open and non-empty, so contains a pair of small open balls $U\subsetneq V$. Now take $C=U^c$. This is closed and contains $A\cup B$ by construction, and is (path) connected when $n\geq 2$.